# Failed to connect to server port 443: Connection refused

Tags: linux, apache2

I have a web server running on my server at 127.0.0.1:8088
And I want to access it from internet.

Output of ss -nplut with running web server :

```
tcp LISTEN 0 1024 127.0.0.1:8088 0.0.0.0:* users:(("ctprods",pid=2042,fd=9))
```

Output ss -nplut |grep 443

```
tcp LISTEN 0 511 *:443 *:*
```

I created an apache virtual host (site enabled, apache reloaded) :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName cyprientaque.com
    ServerAlias ctprods.cyprientaque.com

    ServerAdmin cyprien@gmail.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

#       RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =ctprods.cyprientaque.com
#       RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

     <Proxy *>
             Require all granted
     </Proxy>
             ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8088/
             ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8088/

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/ctprods.cyprientaque.com-0001/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/ctprods.cyprientaque.com-0001/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I created an ssl certificate with lets encrypt :

```
Certificate Name: ctprods.cyprientaque.com-0001
Serial Number: 39538aec7472a644e8d22887f858de17177
Domains: ctprods.cyprientaque.com
Expiry Date: 2020-11-17 10:59:58+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/ctprods.cyprientaque.com-0001/fullchain.pem
Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/ctprods.cyprientaque.com-0001/privkey.pem
```

I have an A record in my dns provider for ctprods.cyprientaque.com pointing to my server IP

But when I try to access to my server with curl, I get an error :

```
$ curl -X GET https://ctprods.cyprientaque.com/projects
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ctprods.cyprientaque.com port 443: Connection refused
```

And I cannot see the request tcpdump port 443..

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>` No wonder, you cannot join 443. You declared port 80 instead of 443.

Comment: woops, my bad, that is a copy paste error

Comment: The network error is solved, now I'm trying to start the binary at reboot. I accepted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Your Apache is not listening on port 443. You configured your VirtualHost only for HTTP, not fot HTTPS. Configure a second VirtualHost with Port 443 and your certificates and make sure you have a `Listen 443` directive in your Apache config. Your certificates don't belong in the `:80` VirtualHost.</del>

The above was based on wrong information in the question. Whatever you did in the meantime, your server is now rechable via HTTPS.

```
$ curl -X GET https://ctprods.cyprientaque.com/projects
"Invalid JWT"
```

Comment: My bad, that is a copy paste error, my virtual host has port 443

Comment: Nevertheless, it is not listening on port 443.

Comment: You need a `Listen 443` directive in your Apache config and of course mod_ssl loaded.

Comment: I have this in my ports.conf file : 

```Listen 80
Listen 4554

<IfModule ssl_module>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>
```
And mod_ssl loaded

Comment: Please run `ss -nplut |grep 443` and edit the output into your question.

Comment: Yes that was ambigous, it's done

Comment: Well, your website is reachable for me.

Comment: In theory or pratically ? 
Here is what I have when I do a curl :

``` curl -X GET https://ctprods.cyprientaque.com/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ctprods.cyprientaque.com port 443: Connection refused ```

Comment: Ah ! I had a redirection on my hosts file pointing to localhost. Thanks for your help !